# How to split a string by AND positioned outside of nested parenthesis?

Tags: javascript, regex

Split string with **AND** which should be outside the round parenthesis and should not match nested parenthesis also.
Ex:

```
AA:1 AND BB:xyz AND C:(D:1 AND E:23 AND F:(21))
```

The expected result is:

```
AA:1
BB:xyz
C:(D:1 AND E:23 AND F:(21))
```

Ex:

```
(A:1 AND B:xyz AND C:(D:1 AND E:23 AND F:(21)))
```

The expected result is:

```
(A:1 AND B:xyz AND C:(D:1 AND E:23 AND F:(21)))
```

I tried with `AND (?![^(]*))` this regex but this won't work for nested parenthesis.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee I tried with ` AND (?![^(]*\))` but in this issue is that if nested parenthesis is there then it will split data.

Comment: A simple solution is possible if you use stack for maintaining brackets. I can post a solution which involves stacks not regex, if you want.

Comment: @PawanSharma plzz add it. I'll try it

Comment: Please check the answer

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: @Toto What I tried is there in the description.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do this using regex, but using stack it works ( not the most optimised solution though ).

```js
const subjectString = 'A:1 AND B:xyz AND C:(D:1 AND E:23 AND F:(21))'

let bracketStack = []
let splitIndices = []
let result = ''

for (let i = 0; i < subjectString.length; i++) {
  switch (subjectString.charAt(i)) {
    case '(':
      bracketStack.push('(')
      break
    case ')':
      if (!bracketStack.length) {
        throw new Error('Invalid Bracket found')
      }
      bracketStack.pop()
      break
    default:
      if (subjectString.charAt(i) === 'A') {
        if (subjectString.charAt(i+1) === 'N' && subjectString.charAt(i+2) === 'D') {
          if (!bracketStack.length) {
            splitIndices.push(i)
          }
          i += 2
        }
      }
  }
}

splitIndices.push(-1)

for (let i = 0; i < splitIndices.length; i++) {
  let startIndex = 0
  let endIndex = splitIndices[i]
  if (i !== 0) {
    startIndex = splitIndices[i-1] + 3  
  }
  if (splitIndices[i] === -1) {
    endIndex = subjectString.length
  }
  result += subjectString.substring(startIndex, endIndex).trim()
  result += '\n'
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not easily possible with `JavaScript`'s somewhat crippled regex engine.
But if you're able to use `PCRE` (`Perl`, `PHP`, `Python`'s `regex` module), you could split by

```
(\((?:[^()]*|(?1))+\))(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|AND
```

which works for arbitrarly nested (but balanced) parentheses.
See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ZLewvH/1/).

Comment: Thanks, this is great but I want this to work in Javascript.

Comment: @codebuzzz: That's why I put the preamble in here. With regular expressions alone in JS, this won't be possible - use programming logic which counts parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Used Javascript regex with "negative lookbehind" and split.

The regex:

```
/(?<!\(.+)\sAND\s/
```

Javascript regex in testbench and context using split:

```
const input1 = "AA:1 AND BB:xyz AND C:(D:1 AND E:23 AND F:(21))";
const input2 = "(A:1 AND B:xyz AND C:(D:1 AND E:23 AND F:(21)))";
const regex = /(?<!\(.+)\sAND\s/;

const result1 = getResultAsDecoratedString(input1.split(regex));
alert(result1);

const result2 = getResultAsDecoratedString(input2.split(regex));
alert(result2);

function getResultAsDecoratedString(resultAsArray) {
    let result = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < resultAsArray.length; i++) {
        result += `Group ${i}: '${resultAsArray[i]}'\n`;   
    }

    return result;
}
```

Output:

```
Result1:
Group 0: 'AA:1'
Group 1: 'BB:xyz'
Group 2: 'C:(D:1 AND E:23 AND F:(21))'

Result2:
Group 0: '(A:1 AND B:xyz AND C:(D:1 AND E:23 AND F:(21)))'
```